# Chaining observables

Tags: fabricjs, angular5, rxjs5

I know this has been asked a few times but I cant find a solution that actually works in Angular 5 with rxjs5.

**TL;DR;**
How do I get these 4 observables to run synchronously in sequence:

```
    const getImage$ = this.fileService.getImage(this.shape.imageFile.id);
    const getUrl$ = Observable.create((blob: Blob) => {
        return URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    });
    const fromURL$ = Observable.bindCallback(fabric.Image.fromURL);
    const addImage$ = Observable.create((img: any) => {
        this.shapeElement = img;
        this.shapeGroup = new fabric.Group([this.shapeElement], {
            lockScalingFlip: true,
            centeredRotation: true,
            angle: this.shape.rotation
        });
        this.fabric.add(this.shapeGroup);
    } );
```

and then return the Observable so I can do more things in the subscriber.

Longer version...

I have a file service that requests an image and returns an observable for the blob:

```
getImage(id) => Observable<Blob>
```

I then need to get the url for this blob:

```
URL.createObjectURL(blob)
```

THen I need to load this to a FabricJS canvas, which has a func with a callback.  I create and observable from this:

```
fromURL = Observable.bindCallback(fabric.Image.fromURL)
```

Lastly, I need to fiddle with the image object that is created by Fabric before I return the observable - the subscription has more stuff to update the ui.

```
this.shapeGroup = new fabric.Group([this.shapeElement], {
   lockScalingFlip: true,
   centeredRotation: true,
   angle: this.shape.rotation,
   tag: Date.now()
  });
this.shapeGroup.shapeView = this;
this.shapeGroup.setShadow(this.getShadow());
this.canvas.fabric.add(this.shapeGroup);
```

This is where I get lost.  I've tried to understand mergeMap and map and pipe and a few other things but I cant get this working.

Has anyone here done this sort of thing before?  This does seem overly complex to achieve.

Ive got this for a start:

```
draw(): Observable<ImageView> {  

  const fromURLOb = Observable.bindCallback(fabric.Image.fromURL);

  return Observable.create(o => {
    if (this.shape.imageFile) {
      console.log('started loading');               
      o.next(this.fileService.getImage(this.shape.imageFile.id));
    }
    o.complete();
  })
 ...
```

which works, but after than Im lost.

**Solution!**

Thanks to @Ingo, this is my working version.

```
    draw(): Observable<ImageView> {
      return this.fileService.getImage(this.shape.imageFile.id)
        .map(blob => URL.createObjectURL(blob))
        .switchMap<string, any>(url => {
            return Observable.bindCallback(fabric.Image.fromURL).call(this, url);
        })
        .do<ImageView>(image => {
            this.handleImage(image);
            return this;
        });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things going on here:

1. `URL.createObjectURL` actually is just a synchronous function, it doesn't return an observable. Thus you just use `map` to map the result from `getImage` to the URL.
2. The `fromUrl` call does use a callback, so you can use `bindCallback` as you did; however, `bindCallback` doesn't return an observable (as you indicate), instead it returns a function that returns an observable. So you need to call that function with the URL you got; you can either use `switchMap` or one of its variants in the chain here; since you only deal with "emits once and completes" observables, the differences between these variants don't matter much.
3. The final handling you are doing are actually just a side effect that doesn't affect the value you want to return, thus you can just use a `do` operator to execute a side effect.
4. Your usage of `Observable.create` suggests some misunderstanding. The function passed into `Observable.create` *always* receives an observer as the parameter, not some value. I think you're confusing functions and observables here.

As a result, you can do this:

```js
private handleImage(img: any) {
    this.shapeElement = img;
    this.shapeGroup = new fabric.Group([this.shapeElement], {
        lockScalingFlip: true,
        centeredRotation: true,
        angle: this.shape.rotation
    });

    this.fabric.add(this.shapeGroup);
}

draw() {
  return this.fileService.getImage(this.shape.imageFile.id)
    .map(blob => URL.createObjectURL(blob))
    .switchMap(url => Observable.bindCallback(fabric.Image.fromURL)(url))
    .do(image => this.handleImage(image));
}
```

Comment: Thanks you!  Observable.bindCallback(fabric.Image.fromURL)(url) is telling me Expected 0 arguments, but got 1. :(

Comment: Ah, had to do this:  Observable.bindCallback(fabric.Image.fromURL).call(url) as .fromURL is an object method not a local fun.

Comment: It works!  You did it!  Ive been stuck on this for days.  Do you prefer beer or chocolate? :):)  (I updated above with the final working version)

Comment: Glad it worked out. Small note: the `return this` in the `do` is unnecessary. A side effect doesn't return anything.